# segmentation fault - don't know where the error is

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

**would just like to get some help, i'm new to programming**

I can't figure out where the error is and what is causing it. please help i'm new to programming c, here is my code.  There is a segmentation fault which i'm unable to figure out the cause.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "7struct.h"

struct checks checkbook;
struct checks *start;

void addcheck();
void displayall();
int deletecheck(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

start = NULL;

char input[3];
int choice = 0;

printf("\n\nThis program will gather information from the user, the");
printf("\ninformation that will be taken in from the user will be");
printf("\ncheck number, date, check written to, amount, and");
printf("\ndescription of the transaction.  The user can store up to");
printf("\n10 checks maximum. Each time a check is taken in, it will");
printf("\nbe displayed back to the user then stored.");

while(choice != 4){

    printf("\n\nPlease pick from the following options: ");
    printf("\n\n1. add a check\n2. Display checkbook\n3. Delete check\n4. Exit program\n");
    fgets(input,3,stdin);

    /*this is a check to ensure the default is called in the switch in user inputs wrong input*/
    if(atoi(input) == 0)
    {
        choice = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        choice = atoi(input);
    }

    /*switch statement for the user input, used to call the appropriate function*/
    switch(choice){

        case 1: 

            printf("\n\nYou have choosen to add a check to your checkbook.");
            addcheck( );
            break;

        case 2:

            printf("\n\nYou have choosen to display all checks in your checkbook.");
            displayall( );
            break;

        case 3:

            printf("\n\nYou have choosen to delete a check");
            deletecheck(choice);
            break;

        case 4:

            printf("\n\nYou have choosen to exit the program, Good Bye!");
            return 0;
            break;

        default:

            printf("\n\nYou have entered an invalid entry, please try again.");
            break;

    }

}

printf("\n\nGood Bye!\n");

return 0;   

}

void addcheck( ){

struct checks *cursor = NULL;
struct checks *temp = NULL;
char num[8];
char camount[10];

if(start == NULL){

    while(getchar() != '\n');
    printf("\n\nYour checkbook is empty, we will add your first check!");

    start = (struct checks*) malloc(sizeof(struct checks));
    start->next = NULL;

    printf("\nPlease enter the check number: ");
    fgets(num, 8, stdin);
    start->cnum = atoi(num);

    printf("\nPlease enter the date the check was entered: ");
    fgets(start->date, 20, stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the person or company the check");
    printf("\nwas written to: ");
    fgets((start)->nameto, 50, stdin);

    /*extra check to make sure the user inputs a valid amount*/
    printf("\nPlease enter the amount of the check: ");
    fgets(camount, 10, stdin);
    if(atoi(camount) == 1)
    {
        (start)->amount = atoi(camount);
    }
    else
    {
        while(atoi(camount) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nYou have enter an invalid amount, please try again: ");
            fgets(camount, 10, stdin);
        }
        (start)->amount = atoi(camount);
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter a description of the check: ");
    fgets((start)->description, 100, stdin);

    printf("\n\nHere is the information about the check you have entered: ");
    printf("\n\nCheck number: %i", (start)->cnum);
    printf("\nDate check was written: %s", (start)->date);
    printf("Written to: %s", (start)->nameto);
    printf("Amount of check: %.2f", (start)->amount);
    printf("\nDescription: %s", (start)->description);

}

else
{

    cursor = start;

    while(cursor->next != NULL)
    {

        cursor = cursor->next;

    }

    cursor->next = malloc(sizeof(struct checks));
    temp = cursor->next;

    while(getchar() != '\n');
    printf("\nPlease enter the check number: ");
    fgets(num, 8, stdin);
    temp->cnum = atoi(num);

    printf("\nPlease enter the date the check was entered: ");
    fgets(temp->date, 20, stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the person or company the check");
    printf("\nwas written to: ");
    fgets(temp->nameto, 100, stdin);

    printf("\nPlease enter the amount of the check: ");
    fgets(camount, 10, stdin);

    if(atoi(camount) == 1)
    {
        temp->amount = atoi(camount);
    }
    else
    {
        while(atoi(camount) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\nYou have enter an invalid amount, please try again: ");
            fgets(camount, 10, stdin);

        }
        temp->amount = atoi(camount);
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter a description of the check: ");
    fgets(temp->description, 100, stdin);        

    printf("\n\nHere is the information about the check you have entered: ");
    printf("\n\nCheck number: %i", temp->cnum);
    printf("\nDate check was written: %s", temp->date);
    printf("Written to: %s", temp->nameto);
    printf("Amount of check: $%.2f", temp->amount);
    printf("\nDescription: %s", temp->description);

    return;


}

}

void displayall( ){

struct checks *cursor = NULL;
cursor = start;

if(start == NULL)
{

    printf("\n\nThere are no checks to be displayed.");

}

else
{

    printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------");

    if(cursor->next == NULL)
    {

        printf("\n\nCheck number: %i", cursor->cnum);
        printf("\nDate check was written: %s", cursor->date);
        printf("Written to: %s", cursor->nameto);
        printf("Amount of check: $%.2f", cursor->amount);
        printf("\nDescription: %s", cursor->description);
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------");

    }

    else
    {

        while(cursor->next != NULL)
        {

            printf("\n\nCheck number: %i", cursor->cnum);
            printf("\nDate check was written: %s", cursor->date);
            printf("Written to: %s", cursor->nameto);
            printf("Amount of check: $%.2f", cursor->amount);
            printf("\nDescription: %s", cursor->description);
            printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------");
            cursor = cursor->next;

        }

        printf("\n\nCheck number: %i", cursor->cnum);
        printf("\nDate check was written: %s", cursor->date);
        printf("Written to: %s", cursor->nameto);
        printf("Amount of check: $%.2f", cursor->amount);
        printf("\nDescription: %s", cursor->description);
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}

}

int deletecheck(int choice){

struct checks *cursor;
struct checks *temp;
int checknum;

cursor = start;

printf("\n\ntest %d", start->cnum);

printf("\n\nPlease enter the check number you would like to delete: ");
scanf("%d", &checknum);

if(start == NULL)
{

    printf("\n\nThere are no records in the checkbook to be deleted");

}

else
{

    while(cursor->next != NULL)
    {
        if(cursor->cnum == checknum)
        {   

            printf("\n\ntest\n\n");
            if(start == cursor)
            {

                start = cursor->next;
                free(cursor);
                printf("\n%d", cursor->cnum);
                return 1;

            }

            else
            {
                printf("\n\ntest\n\n");
                temp->next = cursor->next;
                free(cursor);

                return 1;
            }

        }

        else
        {

            temp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;

        }
    }
}

printf("\n\nCheck number: %d, has been deleted", checknum);
return 0;
}
```

> here is my struct below.

```
struct checks
{

int cnum;
char date[20];
char nameto[50];
double amount;
char description[100];
struct checks* next;

};
```

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs in the delete check section, everything else works fine

Comment: Suggest you run your program in a debugger.

Comment: `gdb` and `valgrind` are your friends for this.

Comment: At least you're using `start` before checking if it is NULL, but do debug. That's why it's there.

Comment: The line `printf("\n\ntest %d", start->cnum);` looks suspicious. The fact that it dereferences `start` before the `if(start == NULL)` check a few lines below it.

Comment: `if(start == NULL)` in `deletecheck` is too late.  also `free(cursor);
                printf("\n%d", cursor->cnum);` : Do not use after `free`.

Comment: the print statement was in there because i wanted to help isolate the problem, help me narrow down where the problem starts, and to see if the variable still exists

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me.  I don't know how to really use the gdb.

Comment: It's time to learn gdb now. It's not that complicated, theres are tons of documentation out there.

Comment: `while(choice != 4){` means loop will never execute if choice =4 . case 4 is useless in your code . Tough I have not looked at your segmentation fault , I will look into it

Comment: In which case you are getting segmentation fault . I am not getting any segmentation fault in your program while adding check

Comment: Date is just 2 digit number why you have date[20] which can save 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see segmentation fault, but the following corrected code works.
The key point is to check if cursor is NULL. If you check next member you didn't check the last position of your list.

```
int deletecheck(int choice)
{
    struct checks *cursor;
    struct checks *temp;
    int checknum;

    cursor = start;
    temp = cursor;

    printf("\n\ntest %d", start->cnum);

    printf("\n\nPlease enter the check number you would like to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &checknum);

    if(start == NULL)
    {

        printf("\n\nThere are no records in the checkbook to be deleted");
    }
    else
    {

        do
        {
            if(cursor->cnum == checknum)
            {
                printf("\n\ntest\n\n");
                if(start == cursor)
                {

                    if (cursor->next != NULL)
                    {
                        start = cursor->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        start = NULL;
                    }
                    free(cursor);
                    printf("\n%d", cursor->cnum);
                    return 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n\ntest\n\n");
                    if (cursor->next != NULL)
                    {
                        temp->next = cursor->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp->next = NULL;
                    }
                    free(cursor);

                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                temp = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->next;

            }
        }
        while(cursor != NULL);
    }

    printf("\n\nCheck number: %d, has been deleted", checknum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works! the print statement at the end doesn't print though

Comment: @brusqueboi because of you put `return 1` each time the node to cancel is found. If it's enough for you check as answered to close the question.